# Laravel schema sql

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

so simply i want to select `user name from table users AS created_by`, but after i put this `{{ $result->created_by }}` in blade tamplate it shows this error `"Undefined property: stdClass::$created_by (View: /var/www/hots/resources/views/builds.blade.php)"`. Please help me.

Schema

```
public function index() {

$builds = DB::table('Build_Talents')
    ->join('Builds', 'Builds.BuildID', '=', 'Build_ID')
    ->join('BuildTalents', 'BuildTalents.TalentsID', '=', 'Talents_ID')
    ->join('Heroes', 'Builds.hero', '=' ,'Heroes.HeroID')
    ->join('users', 'Builds.created_by', '=', 'users.id')
    ->select('Heroes.icon', 'Heroes.name', 
        DB::RAW('Builds.name AS build', 'users.name AS created_by')
     )
    ->get();

    return view('builds', compact('builds')); 
}
```

Blade

```
@extends('home')

@section('content')
    @if($builds)
        @foreach($builds as $result)
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <div class="builds">
                    <img src="{{ $result->icon }}" alt="Build icon" />
                    <h2>{{ $result->name }}-{{ $result->build }}</h2>
                    <i>{{ $result->created_by }}</i>
                </div>
            </div>
        @endforeach
    @else
        <p>Nic nenalezeno</p>
    @endif

@endsection
```

Comment: 'created_by' property is missing. Try to `dd($builds)` to see if you have that field in your collection. If not, check your query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead this:

```
DB::RAW('Builds.name AS build', 'users.name AS created_by')
```

use this:

```
DB::raw('Builds.name AS build, users.name AS created_by')
```

`raw()` has only one parameter and you are using two -
[Api](https://laravel.com/api/5.5/Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder.html#method_raw).